# Is it good or bad (performance-wise) to use std::vector<Vec8d>

Tags: c++, simd, vector-class-library

I am using Agner Fog's vectorclass library to use SIMD instructions (AVX specifically) in my application. Since it is best to use struct-of-array datastructures for easily employing SIMD, I quite often use:

```
std::vector<Vec8d> some_var;
```

or even

```
struct some_struct {
    std::vector<Vec8d> a;
    std::vector<Vec8d> b;
}
```

I wonder if this is bad (performance-wise or even just completely wrong?) considering that the std::vector internal Vec8d* array may in fact not be aligned?

Comment: completely depends on what you do with that data-structure

Comment: What does "may in fact not be aligned" mean, and why do you think that is the case?

Comment: data structures don't "perform", operations you apply to data structures do

Comment: if splitting it up means that you no longer have to delete items in the middle of the vector - then yes, it can certainly offer decent performance improvements.

Comment: @underscore_d: it means prior to C++17, `std::vector` didn't respect `alignof(T)` and thus was broken for types like `__m512d` (or Vec8d which wraps it).  But finally C++17 fixed standard allocators to be usable for over-aligned types (more than alignof(max_align_t)).  Some compilers (e.g. MSVC and ICC) only ever use unaligned load/store instructions even when a type like `__m512d` promises that the memory is aligned, but gcc and clang will use `vmovapd` to store `__m512d`.

Answer (score 3):

I would generally use `vector<double>`, and standard SIMD load/store intrinsics to access the data.  That **avoids tying the interface and all code that touches it to that specific SIMD vector width and wrapper library**.  You can still pad the size to a multiple of 8 doubles so you don't have to include cleanup handling in your loops.

However, you might want to **use a custom allocator for that `vector<double>` so you can get it to align your doubles**.  Unfortunately, even if that allocator's underlying memory allocation is compatible with new/delete, it will have a different C++ type than `vector<double>` so you can't freely assign / move it to such a container if you use that elsewhere.

I'd worry that if you *do* ever want to access individual `double` elements of your vector, doing `Vec8vec[i][j]` might lead to much worse asm (e.g. a SIMD load and then a shuffle or store/reload from VCL's `operator[]`) than `vecdouble[i*8 + j]` (presumably just a `vmovsd`), especially if it means you need to write a nested loop where you wouldn't otherwise need one.

`avec.load (&doublevec[8]);` should generate (almost or exactly) identical asm to `avec = Vec8vec[1];`.  If the data is in memory, the compiler will need to use a load instruction to load it.  It doesn't matter what "type" it had; types are a C++ thing, not an asm thing; a SIMD vector is just a reinterpretation of some bytes in memory.

---

But if this is the easiest way you can convince a C++17 compiler to align a dynamic array by 64, then it's maybe worth considering.  Still nasty and will cause future pain if/when porting to ARM NEON or SVE, because Agner's VCL only wraps x86 SIMD last I checked.  Or even porting to AVX2 will suck.

A better way might be a custom allocator (I think Boost has some already-written) that you can use as the 2nd template param to something like `std::vector<double, aligned_allocator<64>>`.  This is also type-incompatible with `std::vector<double>` if you want to pass it around and assign it to other `vector<>`s, but at least it's not tied to AVX512 specifically.

If you *aren't* using a C++17 compiler (so std::vector doesn't respect alignof(T) > alignof(max_align_t) i.e. 16), then don't even consider this; it will fault when compilers like GCC and Clang use `vmovapd` (alignment-required) to store a `__m512d`.

**You'll want to get your data aligned; 64-byte alignment makes a bigger difference with AVX512 than with AVX2 on current AVX512 CPUs (Skylake-X).**

MSVC (and I think ICC) for some reason choose to always use unaligned load/store instructions (except for folding loads into memory source operands even with legacy SSE instructions, thus requiring 16-byte alignement) even when compile-time alignment guarantees exist.  I assume that's why it happens to work for you.

For an SoA data layout, you might want to share a common size for all arrays, and use `aligned_alloc` (compatible with `free`, not `delete`) or something similar to manage sizes for `double *` members.  Unfortunately there's no standard aligned allocator that supports an aligned_realloc, so you always have to copy, even if there was free virtual address space following your array that a non-crappy API could have let your array grow into without copying.  Thanks, C++.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough, argumented answer, I appreciate it. (Although I don't appreciate the '... like a normal person ...' )

Comment: @wvc: it was intended with a wink.  I guess I'm going to have to stop using it if people are finding it rude in text, not amusing. :/

Comment: It's ok. Your answer is full of useful information and I'm actively applying your suggestions - I learned a lot here.

Comment: std::vector<double> is not guaranteed to be properly aligned. std::vector<Vec8d> will be aligned under C++17 which is required for the vector class library anyway.

Answer (score 3):

std::vector will be properly aligned under C++17 which is required for the vector class library anyway. This will work OK. The std::vector template is relatively efficient. Several other standard container templates are very inefficient because they are implemented as linked lists with an awful lot of dynamic memory allocations and de-allocations.

If the size of the array is known at compile time, or if you have a sensible upper limit to the array size, then it may be more efficient to just make an old fashioned C array.

```
const int arraysize = 0x100;
alignas(64) double myarray[arraysize];  // AVX-512 benefits a lot from alignment
...
Vec8d a;
for (int i=0; i < arraysize/a.size(); i += a.size()) {
    a.load(myarray+i);
    // do your calculations here

}
```

If the array size is not known at compile time, then you may simply allocate your own array:

```
Vec8d * mydynamicarray = new Vec8d[mysize];
```

It is good practice to wrap the memory allocation in a container class with a destructor that cleans up the allocation:

```
~myContainerClass() {
    if (mydynamicarray != 0) delete[] mydynamicarray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you intend to use some_struct, but rather than use two vectors, one for each member you may prefer:

```
struct alignas(64) some_struct {
    double[8] a;
    double[8] b;
};

std::vector<some_struct> vector_of_struct_of_arrays{};
```

I find that my code is usually cleaner with this layout and as was mentioned this allows for the use of a different library in future if you couldn't use vectorclass for some reason.

Comment: Remember that C++17 is required for `std::vector<T>` to respect the `alignas(64)`.  In C++14 and earlier, std::vector ignored over-alignment requirements.